# Oozie worflow, configure mapreduce action to run only reducer/combiner on a set of files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, workflow, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I want to configure a mapreduce action in oozie workflow for a existing mapreduce jar(with mapper, reducer and sometimes combiner also) file, such that only reducer/combiner is run on the input files.

Answer (score 0):

All MapReduce jobs must run the map phase, however you can have the mappers pass the data straight through by either:

- In the old MR API using the [`IdentityMapper`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/IdentityMapper.html)
- In the new MR API by not specifying the mapper class at all, which will default to the base [`Mapper`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html) class that acts as an identity mapper